# Orchard returns 404s for all pages

Tags: orchardcms

I'm developing an Orchard site in Visual Studio 2012 and debugging with the built-in dev server. I appear to have done something that has caused Orchard to return "resource not found" (404s) for all pages and show a directory listing on the home page.

Code in Global.asax and in Orchard's warmup module is being run.

Any tips about how to track this problem down? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Most simple way would be to start the site in debug mode and look for exceptions. If none are shown, check to show all thrown exceptions from under exception settings (Ctr+D, Ctrl+E). If none of these work, check the logs. Something like "A tenant could not be started..." should tell you the issue.

Comment: Hint: maybe it's time to start using some form of source control. You would be able to back out changes until it worked again. You could also create a _new_ site and see if the new site worked.

Comment: Guys, Thank you for your quick responses. Good advice from you both. I'm on a steep learning curve with Orchard and in my panic, I forgot the simplest of techniques i.e. look in the logs!

Cut & paste haste meant I had two routes with the same name. - I'll get my coat. :(

Comment: Try remove cache.dat in App_data... even if you go back to what you did maybe cache remembers it! It saved me a lot of times!